# <c:forEach> não funciona

Tags: java, jsp, lista, jstl

Por algum motivo meu `<c:forEach>` não funciona, o meu *for-each* normal, no qual eu faço o `System.out.print` funciona normalmente.

**MODEL:**

```
    package model;

public class ModeloX {

    private int id;
    private String desc;
    private float val;

    public ModeloX() {

    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return desc;
    }

    public void setDesc(String desc) {
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public float getVal() {
        return val;
    }

    public void setVal(float val) {
        this.val = val;
    }


}
```

**JSP:**

```xml
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ page import="java.util.*" %>
<%@ page import="model.ModeloX" %>


<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">

<%

ModeloX mx = new ModeloX();
List<ModeloX> listaObjetos;
listaObjetos = new ArrayList();

listaObjetos = (ArrayList<ModeloX>)request.getAttribute("listaRegistros");
System.out.println("TESTANDO O PRINT");
for(ModeloX obj : listaObjetos){
    System.out.println("ObjetoID: " + obj.getId() + " Descrição do objeto: " + obj.getDesc() + 
            " Valor do obejto: " + obj.getVal());
}
%>

<h1>Página Inicial!</h1>

<c:forEach items="${listaObjetos}" var="item">
  <c:out value="${item.id}"/>
</c:forEach>
```

**Meu console:**

```
TESTANDO O PRINT

    ObjetoID: 1 Descrição do objeto: uma descrição Valor do obejto: 40.2
    ObjetoID: 2 Descrição do objeto: Uma descricao qualquer Valor do obejto: 20.2
    ObjetoID: 3 Descrição do objeto: NOVA DESC ATUALIZADA Valor do obejto: 66.66
    ObjetoID: 5 Descrição do objeto: aaa Valor do obejto: 123.2
```

Como podem ver, minha list está populado eu consigo exibir os valores no console, porém no `<c:forEach>` não aparece nada.

Comment: @Renan Oi, você deve ter notado que não tenho body, nem head, nem nada ai né. Eu fiz uma espécie de single page application, esse conteúdo é "loadado" em um div container, na minha pagina main eu tenho isso aqui <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>, mas mesmo jogando a taglib na minha pagina secundaria eu não consigo retornar o c:foreach

Comment: realmente, parece que eu preciso ter as bibliotecas na pagina secundaria, fiz isso mas continuo sem resultado

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Troque `items="${listaObjetos}"` por `items="${listaRegistros}"`.

O JSP vai procurar por referências a variáveis nos escopos da página, requisição, sessão e aplicação (nessa ordem). Já a sua `listaObjetos` é uma variável local de um scriptlet, não é um lugar onde o JSP irá buscar por referências de variáveis.

Comment: Funcionou, muitíssimo obrigado!